# Simplest format for video

Tags: sound, video, file

I've been dwelling with a question lately,

I can generate screenshots with my library, but i found that i would like to be able to record video from a game.

Since video is just(well-simply enough, yeah) a collection of images, i guess i could easily write "screenshots" into a single file.

I know that makes sense, but the end result won't be understood by any video application around.
That's where the question pumps in,

What is the simplest file format that i can write to, that a video editing application will be able to understand and convert to a format of choice later?

As a bonus: What if i want to add the sound too? What do you think?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Google **"ffmpeg images to video"**, I believe that's what you're looking for. There's nothing wrong with using images to create the end video, like you said that's pretty much what a video is. I'd personally say **go with MPEG-4** for these reasons:

> MPEG-4 is the best option. The mpeg4 stream can be stored in either in
>   the .avi or .mp4 (quicktime) container file: it can support high
>   levels of lossy compression to keep file sizes small and also supports
>   arbitrary frame rates. It is also translates much more easily to other
>   platforms than wmv1 or wmv2.

Good [reference](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/) here.

Hope it helps. I did the same type of project a little while ago, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Really sounds good, and if i take the extra step, maybe i can use it too to play the video within the application! (Perhaps even with audio playback?)

Comment: Be advised: you must pay for a player if you want MPEG-4 to be played by your game. Yes, even FFMpeg. Otherwise MPEG-LA could sue you.

Comment: Good advice, but how would they REALLY know what format the video is in that's packed into YOUR application?